# Não consigo tirar o resultado None deste código

Tags: python, algoritmo

Estou tentando retirar esse `None`, já botei `else`, já botei `add2` e depois defini `add = add2` mas ainda não consegui tirar.

Como fica:

> Qual fruta você quer adicionar à lista? morango
>
> Quer adicionar mais fruta? talvez
>
> Por favor digite sim ou não:
>
> None (e a caixa de texto pra digitar)
>
> (mesmo problema nos dois ifs)

```
frutas = []
novafruta = input('Qual fruta você quer adicionar à lista? ')
frutas.append(novafruta)
add = input('Quer adicionar mais fruta? ')

if add != 'sim' or add != 'não':
    add = input(print('Por favor *digite sim ou não: '))
    
while add == 'sim':
    frutas.append(input('Qual fruta você quer adicionar à lista? '))
    add = input('Quer adicionar mais fruta? ')
    if add != 'sim' or add != 'não':
        add = input(print('Por favor digite sim ou não: '))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lógica é muito complicada e redundante. Eu até mudaria um pouco a forma de responder ao usuário para simplificar o código, mas não sei se pode então vou manter assim.

O maior motivo do erro é que tem um `input()` sem necessidade encapsulando o `print()`. Isso não faz sentido e torna a lógica falha porque a pessoa só tem uma chance de errar, depois dá problema. Então tem que tirar isso, mas tem que consertar todo o resto da lógica.

```
frutas = []
add = 'sim'
while True:
    if add == 'sim':
        frutas.append(input('Qual fruta você quer adicionar à lista? '))
    add = input('Quer adicionar mais fruta? ')
    if add == 'não':
        break
    if add != 'sim' and add != 'não':
        add = print('Por favor digite sim ou não: ')
print(frutas)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/neBOPm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gcpzgjwv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ExitChar2.py).